# Cardinality of $\text{Aut}(G\times G) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. If $|\text{Aut}(G)|$ is known, what can we say about $|\text{Aut}(G\times G)|$ ?

Comment: It's at least $|Aut(G)|^2$. I'm not sure much more can be said, but I am far from knowledgeable about such matters. Perhaps a nice example to look at is $G = \Bbb Z_2^n$; then $Aut(G) = GL_n(\Bbb F_2)$, and the order of this final group is $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(2^n-2^k\right)$. The order of $GL_{2n}$, for large $n$, appears to be roughly $41|GL_n|^4$.

Answer (score 10):

Picking up on Mike Miller's comment, we can do slightly better for a lower bound:
$$\left|\operatorname{Aut}(G\times G)\right|\geq 2\left|\operatorname{Aut}(G)\right|^2.$$
Besides the disjoint copies of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ in  $\operatorname{Aut}(G\times G)$, we also have the automorphism that swaps the two copies of $G$.  Furthermore, for $G\neq 1$, this is the best possible lower bound, as $G = S_{3}$ (symmetric group of degree $3$) shows.

Comment: @user72870. Sorry, do I have a typo there somewhere that I cannot seem to spot?  We have $\operatorname{Aut}(S_3)\cong S_{3}$, of order $6$, and $\operatorname{Aut}(S_3\times S_3)$ has order $72 = 2\cdot 6^2$.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, I meant to say "How do you show that $|\text{Aut}(S_3^2)|=2⋅3!^2$ ?"

Comment: @user72870. I wrote a little Maple script to find the smallest example achieving the bound. You could do this with GAP as well.

Comment: This is the best possible *polynomial* lower bound. The best possible lower bound of all would trivially be $\min\limits_{|{\rm Aut}(G)|=n}|{\rm Aut}(G\times G)|$.